# How can I specify mail "MX" records on the "A" record server

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-zone, dynamic-dns, ddns

My internet provider automatically creates a dynamic dns that points a name like `client120.example.com` to my dynamic ip address.

I see this is done by replying with a DNS "A" record containing my IP.

Is it possible on my local bind server to specify additional DNS entries for this domain ? (like MX/mail and such)

I created MX records but when quering from online services it only shows a single DNS record, the "A" record pointing name to my IP.

Are there additional DNS settings that allows my computer to reply with more records or parent DNS server at my host can lock me from doing this ?

Comment: ```Is it possible on my local bind server to specify additional DNS entries for this domain ? (like MX/mail and such)``` it's possible, but your provider must configure his dns in specific way.

Answer (score 0):

Such a complication is generally not supported as there typically is a single authoritative zone, so if you wanted to run your own DNS zone that adds random records you would either need to find a DNS server that supports that complication, or kluge it together with scripts that would consult DNS server A and when that changes update the zone for your DNS server B, and then point what clients need to be pointed at B and not A plus the usual fun debugging all this when something breaks or goes awry.

The more sensible approach would be for your internet provider to provide support for setting MX records somehow, as that way there's a single authoritative zone. Another option would be to have an internal view of DNS, but in that case the internal view typically does not care what is set externally by the internet provider, so there would be no script kluge going on to ensure that some records get copied from one zone to another.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to set the `MX` record when updating the `A` record.  The `MX` record points to the `A` record so the IP address of the mail server will be updated when the `A` record is updated.  Related records for `SPF`, `DKIM`, and `DMARC` also don't need to updated if the IP address changes.

While you can run an `MX` on a dynamic IP address, you will have difficulties sending mail directly.  Use your providers email relay server for outgoing email.